# How can I know if an user deleted an element in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using jQuery to detect if an @ symbol has been inserted into a contenteditable div. When this is detected an ajax request is fired to the server to retrieve a list of users. A user would then click on the username (the function adduser will fire) and it will create a disabled textarea in the div.
Then I create an input dynamically with the id of the user selected as value (to notify them)

The problem I have is that if the users delete a textarea (a username) with the keyboard or even the mouse from the contenteditable div, How do I know which textarea it is and so remove too the input which has the user id as value?

My script:

```js
function adduser(fname, lname, id, q)
    {
        var fname = fname;
        var lname = lname;
        var id = id;
        var word = '@' + q;
        var iid = 'id' + id;
    
      var old=$("#contentbox").html();
        var content=old.replace(word,""); 
        
    $("#contentbox").html(content);
        
    var E="<textarea class='textareamention' name="+id+" id="+iid+"  disabled >"+fname+"</textarea>";
                
    $("#contentbox").append(E);
                
      $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'mention[]', id: id, value: id}).appendTo('#post');
    }
```

Comment: Loop thru all the inputs. If a corresponding textarea still exists then keep the input; if not then remove the input.

Comment: Sounds good, but please how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here goes ...

*A* way ahead - maybe not the only one - is to use Mutation Observers, more particularly the [Mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary), library - to watch your `#contentbox` for changes. The Mutation-summary documentation even mentions this particular usage case - see last bullet point under [What is it useful for?](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary#what-is-it-useful-for).

The advantage over event handling is that you don't need to predict every type of event that might cause deletion of a textarea.

A few warnings though :

- Mutation Observers are currently supported only by the major browsers - Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE11. "In the future it will be implemented in other browsers", we are told.
- Mutation-summary hasn't been updated for some 3 years.
- I have not actually used Mutation-summary in anger - I've only read the documentation.

Once a mutation is observed, there must be a number of ways to handle removal of a corresponding element.

One way, as I suggested in the comments above, would be to loop through all the inputs and remove any of them for which its corresponding textarea no longer exists.

However, I think there's a cleaner way.

First, install the [Mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary), library on the page (a `<script src="...">` tag, like jQuery).

Then, modify `adduser()` to include a custom EventListener, `removeRelatedElements`, attached to your `<textarea>` elements :

```
function adduser(fname, lname, id, q) {
    $('<textarea class="textareamention" name=' + id + ' id=id' + id + ' disabled>' + fname + '</textarea>')
    .on('removeRelatedElements', function() {
        $input.remove(); // $input is held in a closure
    })
    .appendTo($("#contentbox").html($("#contentbox").html().replace('@' + q, '')));

    var $input = $('<input/>')
    .attr({
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'mention[]',
        'id': id,
        'value': id
    })
    .appendTo('#post');
}
```

Now, you should be able to use Mutation-summary to observe changes to `#contentbox` and, when a textArea is removed, trigger its custom `removeRelatedElements` event, causing the corresponding `<input>` element also to be removed.

```
var observer = new MutationSummary({
    queries: [
        { element: '#contentbox' } // jQuery-like selector
    ],
    callback: function(summaries) {
        summaries[0].removed.forEach(function(removedEl) {
            // Here, you should be able to write POJS or jQuery, or a mixture
            if(removedEl.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
                $(removedEl).trigger('removeRelatedElements').off('removeRelatedElements'); // remove the corresponding input element and detatch the custom handler to keep things clean
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That's the gist of it anyway. You may well need to do some debugging.

**EDIT:**

OK, the above attempt doesn't work due to `$("#contentbox").html().replace('@' + q, '')`, which replaces the DOM hierarchy within #contentbox. In the process, our `.on('removeRelatedElements', ...)` event handlers get irrevocably blitzed and thereafter `.trigger('removeRelatedElements')` fails silently.

We have to revert to "plan A". At each mutation of `.textareamention`, you need to find and remove any input for which there is no corresponding textarea.

It's tempting to think you can simply work with `summaries[0].removed` as before, but no. The problem there is that `summaries[0].removed` includes references to the textareas that were removed during the `replace('@' + q, '')` process. Consequently *all* corresponding input elements get removed, including the one that was just added! The nett effect is that the expected input never appears.

Fortunately, the workaround is simple. We can completely ignore `summaries` and work with `$("#contentbox textarea.textareamention")` as a start point at each observed mutation. Don't worry if you can't grasp this point - it's not obvious. I discovered it by trial and error.

Here's the code :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var counter = 0; // integer, for associating each <textarea> with its <input>

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var q = " ";

        $('<textarea class="textareamention ' + counter + '" disabled></textarea>') // include `counter` as a className
        .text(counter)  // for demo purposes
        .appendTo($("#contentbox").html($("#contentbox").html().replace('@' + q, '')));

        var $input = $('<input/>').attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'mention[]',
            'value': counter // for demo purposes
        })
        .data('counter', counter) // bind the current counter value to this <input>
        .appendTo('#post');
        counter++;
    });

    var observer = new MutationSummary({
        'queries': [
            { element: '.textareamention' }
        ],
        'callback': function(summaries) {
            // Remove all inputs for which there is no corresponding textarea.
            var $textareas = $("#contentbox textarea.textareamention"); // all textareas
            $("#post input").filter(function(index, element) {
                return $textareas.filter('.' + $(element).data('counter')).length === 0;
            }) // filter to find any input for which there is no corresponding textarea ...
            .remove(); // ... and remove it/them.
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/13z7smbk/1/)**. Note: in the fiddle, all the above code appears at the *bottom* of the javascript frame.

Comment: Hi thank you for your solution. I tried it but nothing happened... I don't understant the use of the event removeRelatedElements. I didn't find it in the MEntion Summary source

Comment: I tried debugging and I notice that the event removeRelatedElements is not fired... @Roamer-1888

Comment: jQuery allows you to "invent" events. `removeRelatedElements` is a custom event invented by me - you won't find it documented anywhere. If the event doesn't fire, then I would guess that either there's an uncaught error in my code, or the event handler is removed from the element before it is triggered. If it's the latter, I will have to modify the process.

Comment: To debug, I would start in the "callback" function. Add a `console.log(...)` statement to see whether 'removeRelatedElements' is triggered.

Comment: I tried to debug by adding console.log(..) but nothing happened so 'removeRelatedElements' is not triggered

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: Maybe the query `{ element: '#contentbox' }` is wrong.  If so then its quite possible that the callback won't fire.

Comment: The contenteditable div id is contentbox so it should work, right ?

Comment: or should I change 'element' by another selector ?

Comment: Oh it worked! I change contentbox by the textarea class '.textareamention' Thank you so much!!!

Comment: But when i have manu textareas it only works with the last one. Do you know why? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @KhalidAskia, I can't immediately see why it should work like that. You already have more experience of `MutationSummary` than I have. You are rapidly becoming an expert. Keep on playing with it until you have full control. It will come.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help! But I cant find the solution of the problem I have. When I enter many textarea only the last one have the event removeRelatedElements

Comment: If you can you make a working example in codepen or jsfiddle, I'll see if I can debug it for you.

Comment: Hi, here is the jsfidle https://jsfiddle.net/khalidaskia/13z7smbk/  But there is a problem i copy paste my code but on the jsfidle file even woth on textarea the event removeRelatedElements is not fired. I copy paste directly the mutation-summary code in the jsfidle file. Can you please check it?

Comment: OH WOW you're amazing! that worked! Thank you so much!!!!!! I really appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

Try to register a callback function while deleting the textarea, like this:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function del(id) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
      alert(id);
      $("#id"+id).remove();
    }
  }

  function adduser(fname, lname, id, q) {
    var fname = fname;
    var lname = lname;
    var id = id;
    var word = '@' + q;
    var iid = 'id' + id;

    var old=$("#contentbox").html();
    var content=old.replace(word,""); 

    $("#contentbox").html(content);

    var E="<textarea onkeydown='del("+id+")' class='textareamention' name="+id+" id="+iid+" >"+fname+"</textarea>";

    $("#contentbox").append(E);

    $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'mention[]', id: id, value: id}).appendTo('#post');
  }
</script>

<body>
<div id='contentbox'></div>

<button onclick="adduser(123, 123, 123, 123)">Click me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works when I click on the textarea but how can I do it also when I delete it by the keyboard key (backspace)?

Comment: @KhalidAskia I have updated the code. You only have to detect the **onkeydown** event for each textarea, and check which key is down in **del()**.

Comment: I really apreciate your help but I accepted the other solution, it is eactly what I was looking for. Thank you